# Time in getting single elements from data.table and data.frame objects

Tags: performance, r, dataframe, data.table

In my work I use to have several tables (customer details, transaction records, etc). Being some of them are very big (millions of rows), I've recently switched to the `data.table` package (thanks Matthew). However, some of them are quite small (few hundreds of rows and 4/5 column) and are called several times. Therefore I started to think about `[.data.table` overhead in **retrieving** data rather then set()ting value as already clearly described in `?set`, where, regardless the size of table one item is set in around 2 microseconds (depending on cpu).

However it doesn't seem to exist the equivalent of `set` for getting a value from a `data.table` knowing the exact row and column. A sort of *loopable* `[.data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

m = matrix(1,nrow=100000,ncol=100)
DF = as.data.frame(m)
DT = as.data.table(m)  # same data used in ?set

> microbenchmark(DF[3450,1] , DT[3450, V1], times=1000) # much more overhead in DT

Unit: microseconds
expr     min      lq   median      uq      max neval
DF[3450, 1]  32.745  36.166  40.5645  43.497  193.533  1000
DT[3450, V1] 788.791 803.453 813.2270 832.287 5826.982  1000

> microbenchmark(DF$V1[3450], DT[3450, 1, with=F], times=1000)  # using atomic vector and
                                                                # removing part of DT overhead
Unit: microseconds                                              
expr     min      lq  median      uq      max neval
DF$V1[3450]   2.933   3.910   5.865   6.354   36.166  1000
DT[3450, 1, with = F] 297.629 303.494 305.938 309.359 1878.632  1000

> microbenchmark(DF$V1[3450], DT$V1[3450], times=1000) # using only atomic vectors
Unit: microseconds
        expr   min    lq median    uq    max neval
 DF$V1[3450] 2.933 2.933  3.421 3.422 40.565  1000    # DF seems still a bit faster (23%)
 DT$V1[3450] 3.910 3.911  4.399 4.399 16.128  1000
```

The last method is indeed the best one to fast retrieve a single element several times. However, `set` is even faster

```
> microbenchmark(set(DT,1L,1L,5L), times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                expr   min    lq median    uq    max neval
 set(DT, 1L, 1L, 5L) 1.955 1.956  2.444 2.444 24.926  1000
```

**the question is**: if we can `set` a value in 2.444 microseconds shouldn't be possible  to *get* a value in a smaller (or at least similar) amount of time? Thanks.

EDIT:
 adding two more options as suggested:

```
> microbenchmark(`[.data.frame`(DT,3450,1), DT[["V1"]][3450], times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                        expr    min     lq median     uq      max neval
 `[.data.frame`(DT, 3450, 1) 46.428 47.895 48.383 48.872 2165.509  1000
            DT[["V1"]][3450] 20.038 21.504 23.459 24.437  116.316  1000
```

which unfortunately are not faster than the previous attempts.

Comment: I agree with your question that the overhead could/should be not this much. To give an alterantive though, how about `DT[["V1"]][3450]`??

Comment: Or use data.frame subsetting: `'[.data.frame'(DT,3450,1)` (`'` are supposed to be backticks.)

Comment: But I am a bit skeptical about your perceived need for repeated subsetting. Often this means you can optimize by changing your algorithm.

Comment: @Roland, it doesn't matter if there's a repeated need for subsetting or not. The question (last line) is very clear.

Comment: @Arun I agree and have already upvoted. However, I still believe my comment is valid.

Comment: @Michele, about your edit, you're totally right. I dint see the part about `DT$V1[3450]`.

Comment: @Arun @Roland Thanks guys for your interest. Regarding Roland opinion I would say that he's right in most situation. Even if for me would mean re-design the entire solution. However, my question is just what you read in the last line, which is also based on the idea of M Dowle of having a 'loopable' `:=`, which is `set`

Comment: +1. For your use case ("few hundreds of rows and 4/5 column", which should take up a small amount of memory), maybe you could store copies of your small data.tables as matrices, and use the latter whenever you're accessing elements...? On my computer, `m[3450,1]` is still ~10x faster than `DT$V1[3450]`; I don't think you'll be able to achieve that kind of performance with anything but a matrix. On the other hand, every column in a matrix needs to have the same class...

Comment: @Frank exactly! that's the reason why I'm stick with only DF and DT. But, in the future, I will rehsape my solution and may try to work out a way to use some matrices (for the numeric and date columns) with some integer ids to link them back. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try `.subset2(DT, "V1")[3450]` - `.subset2` is the internal version of `[[` that doesn't do S3 dispatch and is much faster.

Comment: @hadley thanks a lot. Your comment is indeed the answer. Why don't you write your solution below? thanks.

Comment: @Michele, you should write it as an answer and mark it as such instead of editing your question. Better to get the question answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @hadley we have the solution!

```
> microbenchmark(DT$V1[3450], set(DT,1L,1L,5L), .subset2(DT, "V1")[3450], times=1000, unit="us")
Unit: microseconds
                     expr   min    lq median    uq    max neval
              DT$V1[3450] 2.566 3.208  3.208 3.528 27.582  1000
      set(DT, 1L, 1L, 5L) 1.604 1.925  1.925 2.246 15.074  1000
 .subset2(DT, "V1")[3450] 0.000 0.321  0.322 0.642  8.339  1000
```