# data.table vs bigmemory for read-only access to large objects

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a large data.frame of 1,000,000 rows containing 2 string and 6 integer columns. Iterating sequentially through this data.frame takes an awful lot of time, even without modifying it. This is the basic loop I'm using:

```
for( i in 1:1000000 ) {
  varA = mydf[i, "varA"]
  varB = mydf[i, "varB"]
  ...
}
```

It takes about 10 seconds to process 100 rows and I have several 1M blocks of data to go through. I don't need to modify the data.frame but I do need to read the rows sequentially (that is why I chose to run a for loop rather than calling apply).

In this situation would you rather use a data.table or bigmemory object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882049/time-in-getting-single-elemets-from-data-table-and-data-frame-objects but note that it's unlikely that you *actually* need to do this, and more likely have some sort of an inefficient algorithm

Comment: What do you mean I have an inefficient algorithm? What's wrong with sequential processing?

Comment: There is usually a better, non-sequential and much faster way in R, so I recommend posting the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm processing time-series records from a database, 1,000,000 at the time. Each record is dependent on the updates seen in the previous rows and the end result is a matrix of similar dimensions than the original database table.

Comment: And you seriously expect some magical answer from that vague description?

Comment: You're best bet is to try them both.  No one is in a better position than yourself to benchmark between the two options given your algorithm.  My intuition says that since bigmemory's purpose is dealing with objects that are bigger than phys memory that if you have enough RAM for data.table to work at all that it will be faster.

Comment: Seriously needs more information... after 1.5 years this has neither been answered or closed. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Use data.table:

```
setDT(mydf)[, c('varA', 'varB')]
```

For example:

```
> mydf <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(1e8), nc = 100))# 1E6 rows
> colnames(mydf) <- paste0('var', 1:100)
```

using data.table package

```
> head(mydf[, c('var50', 'var75')])

       var50      var75
1: 1.77199144  2.32235675
2: 0.06925491 -1.03333482
3: 0.05529698 -0.56474744
4: 0.07815707  0.06754285
5: 0.20430406 -2.31359882
6: 1.26963312 -1.18745481
```

machine time:

```
> system.time(mydf[, c('var50', 'var75')])


user  system elapsed 
0.00    0.01    0.02
```