# Time to get elements from a matrix object

Tags: r, matrix, microbenchmark

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882049/time-in-getting-single-elemets-from-data-table-and-data-frame-objects) I ran a microbenchmark to read a single element from a large matrix. I was surprised to see how much performances degrade when using row names:

```
m = matrix(1, nrow=1000000, ncol=10)
rownames(m) = as.character(1:1000000)
microbenchmark(m["3450", 1], m[3450, 1], times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
         expr       min        lq      median          uq        max neval
 m["3450", 1] 176465.55 183443.369 185321.5540 185982.0840 522346.477  1000
 m[3450, 1]        3.19      3.445     10.7155     14.1545     29.897  1000
```

I absolutely need to use row names to read my matrix elements. How can I improve performances?

*UPDATE*

I added benchmark results from Geoffrey answer and subset(). I have no idea why but subset() has much better read-only performances ([[]] allows for assignment, subset() does not):

```
 microbenchmark(m["3450", 1], m[["3450", 1]], m[3450, 1], .subset(m, 1)["3450"], .subset(m, 1)[3450], times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                  expr        min         lq      median          uq        max neval
          m["3450", 1] 176667.252 180197.435 181969.2900 185090.9155 254075.814  1000
        m[["3450", 1]]    144.732    145.341    151.1440    191.9960   1096.183  1000
            m[3450, 1]      2.900      3.290      4.4400      6.5025     22.391  1000
 .subset(m, 1)["3450"]      2.704      3.140      4.1285     14.8740     43.134  1000
   .subset(m, 1)[3450]      2.460      2.815      3.2680     13.0300     38.105  1000
```

Comment: Why is this a limitation for you? Why do you need to subset like this so often that this matters? Why do you need to access matrix elements repeatedly by rownames? Maybe, you should rethink your algorithm?

Comment: From `?.subset`: `except that methods dispatch does not take place`. That's why it's faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use m[["3450, 1]]. The '[[' operator selects only a single element (I believe the first one) and then returns it. '[' is used to select more than one element. Ideally you would not characters as rownames in the first place ...

```
microbenchmark(m["3450", 1], m[["3450", 1]],m[3450, 1], times=1000)
Unit: nanoseconds
           expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
   m["3450", 1] 74898303 76755304 78038970 87569666 231740997  1000
 m[["3450", 1]]    30790    32657    48673    55671    241340  1000
     m[3450, 1]      623     1245     2800     6532     26125  1000
```

Comment: Still almost 20x times slower. Isn't matrix using hash structures to key the element cell index from the row names?

Comment: @RobertKubrick it constructs the hash on the fly, and only when more efficient than a linear search, i.e. when you are subsetting by many names.