# Most efficient way (fastest) to modify a data.frame using indexing

Tags: r, performance, data.table

### Little introduction to the question :

I am developing an ecophysiological model, and I use a reference class list called `S` that store every object the model need for input/output (e.g. meteo, physiological parameters etc...). 
This list contains 5 objects (see example below):
 - two dataframes, `S$Table_Day` (the outputs from the model) and `S$Met_c`(the meteo in input), which both have variables in columns, and observations (input or output) in row.
 - a list of parameters `S$Parameters`.
 - a matrix
 - a vector

The model runs many functions with a daily time step. Each day is computed in a for loop that runs from the first day i=1 to the last day i=n. This list is passed to the functions that often take data from `S$Met_c` and/or `S$Parameters` in input and compute something that is stored in `S$Table_Day`, using indexes (the ith day). `S` is a Reference Class list because they avoid copy on modification, which is very important considering the number of computations.

### The question itself :

As the model is very slow, I am trying to decrease computation time by micro-benchmarking different solutions.
Today I found something surprising when comparing two solutions to store my data. Storing data by indexing in one of the preallocated dataframes is longer than storing it into an undeclared vector. After reading [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-higher-stonger-a-guide-to-speeding-up-r-code-for-busy-people/), I thought preallocating memory was always faster, but it seems that R performs more operations while modifying by index (probably comparing the length, type etc...).

**My question is** : is there a better way to perform such operations ? In other words, is there a way for me to use/store more efficiently the inputs/outputs (in a data.frame, a list of vector or else) to keep track of all computations of each day ? For example would it be better to use many vectors (one for each variable) and regroup them in more complex objects (e.g. list of dataframe) at then end ?

By the way, am I right to use Reference Classes to avoid copy of the big objects in `S` while passing it to functions and modify it from within them ?

Reproducible example for the comparison:

```
SimulationClass <- setRefClass("Simulation",
                           fields = list(Table_Day = "data.frame",
                                         Met_c= "data.frame",
                                         PerCohortFruitDemand_c="matrix",
                                         Parameters= "list",
                                         Zero_then_One="vector"))
S= SimulationClass$new()
# Initializing the table with dummy numbers : 
S$Table_Day= data.frame(one= 1:10000, two= rnorm(n = 10000), three= runif(n = 10000),Bud_dd= rep(0,10000))
S$Met_c= data.frame(DegreeDays= rnorm(n=10000, mean = 10, sd = 1))


f1= function(i){
    a= cumsum(S$Met_c$DegreeDays[i:(i-1000)])
}

f2= function(i){
    S$Table_Day$Bud_dd[(i-1000):i]= cumsum(S$Met_c$DegreeDays[i:(i-1000)])
}

res= microbenchmark(f1(1000),f2(1000),times = 10000)
autoplot(res)
```

And the result :
[image: Autoplot from Microbenchmark]

Also if someone has any experience in programming such models, I am deeply interested in any advice for model development.

Comment: if you are interested in performances regarding data frames you should have a look to the library `data.table`

Comment: @JulienNavarre yes I already use it to perform computations on the `S$Table_Day` dataframe for complex tasks, but do you think using a data.table instead of a data.frame is faster to modify values by indexing ? (I am not talking about performing computations but rather store the results in the table).

Comment: Oh yeah! Check out [data.table vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) on this matter, you should make sure to do it the best way, but it is 155 times faster

Comment: Is the 10,000 row range you gave in your example representative of your actual data size? The fastest method will likely differ depending on the size.

Comment: @MattSummersgill yes absolutely. It is 10,000 to 15,000 long. S$Table_Day has 157 columns, and S$Met_c has 48 columns (and same number of rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read more about the question, and I'll just write here for prosperity some of the solutions that were proposed on other posts.

Apparently, reading **and** writing are both worth to consider when trying to reduce the computation time of assignation to a data.frame by index.
The sources are all found in other discussions:

- [How to optimize Read and Write to subsections of a matrix in R (possibly using data.table)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125947/6947799)
- [Faster i, j matrix cell fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817341/faster-i-j-matrix-cell-fill?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Time in getting single elements from data.table and data.frame objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882049/time-in-getting-single-elements-from-data-table-and-data-frame-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Several solutions appeared relevant :

1. Use a `matrix` instead of a data.frame if possible to leverage in place modification [(Advanced R)](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification-in-place).
2. Use a `list` instead of a data.frame, because `[<-.data.frame` is not a primitive function [(Advanced R)](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification-in-place).
3. Write functions in C++ and use `Rcpp` ([from this source] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125947/6947799))
4. Use `.subset2` to read instead of `[` ([third source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882049/time-in-getting-single-elements-from-data-table-and-data-frame-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1))
5. Use `data.table` as recommanded by @JulienNavarre and @Emmanuel-Lin and the different sources, and use either `set` for `data.frame` or `:=` if using a `data.table` is not a problem.
6. Use `[[` instead of `[` when possible (index by one value only). This one is not very effective, and very restrictive, so I removed it from the following comparison.

---

Here is the analysis of performance using the different solutions :

### The code :

```
# Loading packages :
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

# Creating dummy data :
SimulationClass <- setRefClass("Simulation",
                               fields = list(Table_Day = "data.frame",
                                             Met_c= "data.frame",
                                             PerCohortFruitDemand_c="matrix",
                                             Parameters= "list",
                                             Zero_then_One="vector"))
S= SimulationClass$new()
S$Table_Day= data.frame(one= 1:10000, two= rnorm(n = 10000), three= runif(n = 10000),Bud_dd= rep(0,10000))
S$Met_c= data.frame(DegreeDays= rnorm(n=10000, mean = 10, sd = 1))

# Transforming data objects into simpler forms :
mat= as.matrix(S$Table_Day)
Slist= as.list(S$Table_Day)
Metlist= as.list(S$Met_c)
MetDT= as.data.table(S$Met_c)
SDT= as.data.table(S$Table_Day)

# Setting up the functions for the tests :
f1= function(i){
    S$Table_Day$Bud_dd[i]= cumsum(S$Met_c$DegreeDays[i])
}
f2= function(i){
    mat[i,4]= cumsum(S$Met_c$DegreeDays[i])
} 
f3= function(i){
    mat[i,4]= cumsum(.subset2(S$Met_c, "DegreeDays")[i])
} 
f4= function(i){
    Slist$Bud_dd[i]= cumsum(.subset2(S$Met_c, "DegreeDays")[i])
}
f5= function(i){
    Slist$Bud_dd[i]= cumsum(Metlist$DegreeDays[i])
}
f6= function(i){
    set(S$Table_Day, i=as.integer(i), j="Bud_dd", cumsum(S$Met_c$DegreeDays[i]))
}
f7= function(i){
    set(S$Table_Day, i=as.integer(i), j="Bud_dd", MetDT[i,cumsum(DegreeDays)])
}
f8= function(i){
    SDT[i,Bud_dd := MetDT[i,cumsum(DegreeDays)]]
}


i= 6000:6500
res= microbenchmark(f1(i),f3(i),f4(i),f5(i),f7(i),f8(i), times = 10000)
autoplot(res)
```

### And the resulting autoplot :

[image: Autoplot]

With `f1` the reference base assignment, `f2` using a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame`, `f3` using the combination of `.subset2` and `matrix`, `f4` using a `list` and `.subset2`, `f5` using two `list`s (both reading and writing), `f6` using `data.table::set`, `f7` using `data.table::set` and `data.table` for cumulative sum, and `f8`using `data.table` `:=`.

As we can see **the best solution is to use lists** for reading and writing. This is pretty surprising to see that `data.table` is the worst solution. I believe I did something wrong with it, because it is supposed to be the best. If you can improve it, please tell me.

Comment: Very thorough! A couple comments **1:** It Looks like `f2` and `f6` didn't run in the results you posted.  **2:** Did you mean to use `SDT` instead of `S$Table_Day` as the `x` argument of `set()` in `f6` and `f7`? **3:** the `as.integer()` coercion isn't actually necessary here.

Comment: @Matt Summersgill, thank you very much for your comment ! In response to your comments :
**1:** I replaced the image (I picked the wrong one), thank you.

Comment: Sorry, missed some info on my last comment and I can't edit it. Here is the full version :
**1:** I replaced the image (I picked the wrong one), thank you.  
**2:** No, I used deliberately S$Table_Day for `f6` and `f7` as set() is compatible with `data.frame`s. The purpose was to test the power of set()  without interfering with the data structure for this table. And then test `:=` (which is the equivalent), but at the expense of transforming S$Table into a `data.table`.  
**3:** Indeed. I used it to avoid a warning (my `i` was not an integer at first)

Comment: You should check your results are equivalent. See `my_check` in `?microbenchmark`.